# Input field is not updating when its value changes in Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I need to update input value when I type in another input field. The problem is that the value is changing but input field stays empty. How to get the field updated? This is the part of my code not working:

```
<template>
   <input
    v-model="formValues.setValue"
    class="input"
    type="number"
    @input="calcValue"
   >
   <input
    v-model="formValues.getValue" // not updating inside this field
    class="input"
    type="number"
    readonly
   >
</template>
<script>
  export default {
   async setup() {
    const formValues = ref({});
    const calcValue = () => {
        formValues.value.getValue = formValues.value.setValue * 3;
        console.log(formValues.value.getValue); // prints OK
    };
    return {
      formValues,
      calcValue,
    }
   }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: `formValues.value.getValue` is not the same as `formValues.getValue`

Comment: @MattEllen they are the same actually. If I add `formValues.value.getValue = 1` out of `calcValue` function it appears in the input field, just not updating on `@input`.

Comment: You are correct that you do not need to specify `.value` when using a ref variable in your template (it automatically unwraps the value for you), but is there any other code you've not included?  I see you're using an async setup but none of your code is asynchronous.  I copy pasted your code into a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-sunset-vkljmz?file=/src/App.vue) (removing the 'async' to avoid error) and found no problems with the functionality

Comment: Thanks, @yoduh! Yes you are right there is more code and problem wasn't in this part but somewhere else. Thanks for pointing me!